# sql query to return record that has no duplicate record in same table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains record like this.

```
S.No   | Name   |  Date     |  Type  
1      | test   | 2014-1-1  |   In
2      | test   | 2014-1-1  |   Out
3      | test12 | 2014-1-1  |   In
4      | test12 | 2014-1-1  |   Out
5      | test123| 2014-1-1  |   In
```

What is required is an sql query that would return only record that has type=In and no type = out has been done for it on same date. I had tried 
select date,COUNT(*) as count from dbo.TimeCheckInOut where EmployeeNo='E012'  group by Date .This is not working.. how can i return those record whose type is In only

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get *only records that has type=In and no type = out* then I suggest to do it like this:

```
select *
from Table1 as t
where
    t.[Type] = 'In' and
    not exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as tt where tt.Name = t.Name and tt.[Type] = 'Out'
    )
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e429/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Name,Date,Type From
Table 1 Where Type = 'In' And 
              Name Not In (Select Name From Table1 Where Type = 'Out')
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e429/6)**

---

**O/P**

```
SNO NAME    DATE                            TYPE
------------------------------------------------
5   test123 January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000  In
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.type = 'IN' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  table1 t2 WHERE t2.type = 'OUT' AND t2.name = t1.name)
```

The above query will yield the desired output.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8252f/1)

Comment: how's that different from my answer? am I missing something?

Comment: @RomanPekar I am sorry I missed out your answer. I just read the other one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Query..

```
select * from test a
where a.Type='In'
and not exists (select null from test b  where b.Type='Out' and b.Name=a.Name)
```

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d775b/3)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
select in.* 
  from table in 
  left join table out
    on out.name = in.name 
   and in.type = 'In' 
   and out.type = 'Out' 
 where out.name is null
```